# SIGSEGV through writing to local variable

Tags: c++, vector, attributes, local, segmentation-fault

I'm currently encountering the most strange behavior in my C++ project. What I'm trying to do is calculate the euclidean distance between two double vectors (well, actually, vectors of double vectors, hence the m_Data[0].size()).

This is the source:

```
double NEAT::Behavior::Distance_To(NEAT::PhenotypeBehavior* other)
{  
  double sum = 0.0;

  for (int i = 0; i < m_Data[0].size() && i < other->m_Data[0].size(); i++) {
    double x1 = m_Data[0][i];
    double x2 = b->m_Data[0][i];
    double difference = x1 - x2;
    difference *= difference;
    sum += difference;
  }

  return sqrt(sum);
}
```

I initially had all this written in one line, but I've split it up to locate the error. What happens is that after a few thousand calls to this function, it throws a SIGSEGV at the last line of the for loop:

```
sum += difference;
```

I have NO idea how this could happen. I've checked the stack trace, it's from the Distance_To(...) function and it gets thrown at this line precisely. As soon as I comment it out, everything's fine (but of course the function won't work lol). The signal gets thrown at the same time each time I run the program with the same objects interacting.

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I've verified the integrity of the pointers in this method by printing out the needed values before entering the loop. All values get printed correctly. Here is the complete version of the function I used for debugging purposes:

```
double NEAT::Behavior::Distance_To(NEAT::PhenotypeBehavior* other)
{  
  double sum = 0.0;

  Behavior* b = (Behavior*) other;

  // Gets executed without any problems
  if (genomeid == 300 && b->genomeid == 399) {
    std::cout << "PROBLEM CASE" << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "Printing values for 300..." << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_Data[0].size(); i++) std::cout << m_Data[0][i] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Printing values for 399..." << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_Data[0].size(); i++) std::cout << b->m_Data[0][i] << std::endl;
  }

  // Doesn't get executed
  if (m_Data[0].size() != other->m_Data[0].size()) {
    std::cout << "Different sizes, " << m_Data[0].size() << " and " << b->m_Data[0].size() << std::endl;
  }

 // SIGSEGV at size() call
 for (int i = 0; i < m_Data[0].size() && i < b->m_Data[0].size(); i++) {
    double x1 = m_Data[0][i];
    double x2 = b->m_Data[0][i];
    double difference = x1 - x2;
    difference *= difference;

    // If this line gets commented out, no SIGSEGV but the program starts behaving weirdly afterwards (suddenly different sizes after the faulty run)
    sum += difference;
  }

  return sqrt(sum);
}
```

Comment: Is the `b` pointer have a valid address?

Comment: Your parameter `other` is not used.

Comment: Assign the vector sizes to `const` temporary variables.  This should expose any pointer issues.  Also, since `size()` is usually constant, you don't want to call it in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: b is valid. Actually, it's a downcast version of other, I stripped that part from the code snippet for readability and forgot to correct it. I edited that now. Both versions produce the same error. In the previous lines of that method, I access the pointer so I know they're working. Thanks!

Comment: I should point out that I solely use the other pointer to print out debugging information in the left out lines of that function. I don't change anything about the underlying object.

Comment: If it happens at the same time each time, try to figure out what `i` is at that instant. You could then either set a conditional breakpoint when `i` reaches that value and start stepping, or put an `if (i == whatever)` and set a breakpoint on some dummy statement when the condition is true and start stepping.

Comment: Do you have other threads going?

Comment: This program runs sequential. I have a system call to gnu parallel at another place in the program but it doesn't run in the background, I thought maybe some sqlite statements were at fault but from what I saw these also run sequentially. I even checked both vectors for size equality before and the error still occurs. Both vectors have six elements. I'm really confused on why the sum += difference line breaks the whole thing

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Remove the pointer and see if the problem still occurs.  Also review the assembly code generated by the compiler (even step into it with the debugger and verify registers have correct values).

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks for your reply. I updated the question to include the complete version of the function to clarify where everything works and where bad stuff starts to happen. I still have to run valgrind (I don't have any experience with these kinds of tools so far), but that code is part of a slightly bigger program for my master's thesis. The complete code can be found here: https://github.com/ChristophKuhfuss/stneatexperiment with the SIGSEGV getting thrown in multineat/Behavior.cpp.

Comment: The ids 300 and 399 are one problem case I specifically located via debug printing by the way, that's why I check for those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I missed out on some MultiNEAT framework functions I should've used but didn't for initializing the objects etc. Anyways, thanks a lot to all of you, I learned a lot about using valgrind and ASAN (both are really handy and I didn't know about either of them before! lol) and even got a few good articles to read. Duh!

Answer (score 3):

[ASAN](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html) are the tools you should use to identify the root cause of this type of errors. Eventhough the error thrown at line `sum += difference`, your actual error could be somewhere else before hitting this point which corrupts your memory. These tools will help you to track that.

Comment: I am going to try those. Thanks!